# SSL: no alternative certificate subject. RCurl in RStudio

Tags: r, curl, knitr, rcurl

I am trying to conect my RStudio with R Markdown files with my Wordpress. I installed RWordPress, knitr, RCurl, XMLRPC.

When I run knit2wp I get this error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'vivaelsoftwarelibre.com'
```

I am running the latest version of Linux Mint and R. Reading around, I think the problem must be in the RCurl package.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Your assertion is faulty. Esp since [this](https://rud.is/dl/vivaelsoftwarelibre.com.png) is what the latest Firefox has to say about your site's SSL config and [this](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=vivaelsoftwarelibre.com) is what SSL Labs has to say about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because — while the error is reproducible — it has absolutely nothing do to with `R` or `RCurl`.